# the k-SRP stationary Ramsey property

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ramsey-theory, large-cardinals

I would like to know why [here](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/1/1952/files/2020/01/TangIncomp011120a.pdf)
we have 
$$\kappa<\omega$$

in

"where we partition all of
$\kappa<\omega$"

[image]

Comment: I think this is a typo; I believe he's referring to partitioning what he usually denotes by $[\kappa]^{<\omega}$.

Comment: Yes, this is a typo.

Comment: I believe that the author is using $\kappa\to\omega$ for what would be denoted $\kappa\to(\omega)^{<\omega}_2$ in more modern notation

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo And how can I see that the least $2-$SRP is greater than the first weakly compact cardinal ? Also, do they really mean weakly greater ?

Comment: @user122424 A cardinal is weakly compact iff $\kappa\to(\kappa)^2_2$, in $2$-SRP you additionally require that the homogeneous set is stationary

Comment: My suggestion would be to edit the question, now that the typo is resolved and there are no answers yet. Or to ask a new question so it can be answered properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all $\kappa<\omega$ is a typo and should be $[\kappa]^{<\omega}$.

Let me introduce some notation: $$\kappa\to(\alpha)^\gamma_\delta$$
means that every function $f\colon[\kappa]^\gamma\to\delta$ has a homogeneous set of order type $\alpha$, or in other words that there exist $H\in[\kappa]^\alpha$ such that $f\upharpoonright H^\gamma$ is constant. In plain English this means that whenever we colour the subsets of $\kappa$ of cardinality $\gamma$ using $\delta$-many colours, there is an $H\subseteq\kappa$ of order type $\alpha$, such that all all subsets of $H$ of cardinality $\gamma$ have the same colour.

Similarly $$\kappa\to(\alpha)^{<\omega}_\delta$$ means that for every $f\colon[\kappa]^{<\omega}\to\delta$ there is $H\in[\kappa]^\alpha$ such that $f\upharpoonright H^n$ is constant for every $n$.

With this notation, based on the description between brackets, what the author is calling $\kappa\to\omega$ is $\kappa\to(\omega)^{<\omega}_2$ (such cardinals are known as Ramsey cardinals).

To answer the question raised in the comments being $k$-SRP now means that $\kappa\to(\kappa)^k_2$ and furthermore the homogenous $H$ can be chosen to be stationary in $\kappa$. In particular $\kappa$ is $2$-SRP if $\kappa\to(\kappa)^2_2$ and for every $f\colon[\kappa]^2\to 2$ the homogeneous set for $f$ can be chosen to be stationary in $\kappa$. Since $\kappa\to(\kappa)^2_2$ is equivalent to $\kappa$ being weakly compact (see Theorem 7.8 in Kanamori's book) we immediately have that the least $2$-SRP cardinal is at least as big as the least weakly compact one.

Comment: Right. How can I see that $\kappa$ is uncountable ? We have also $\omega \to (\omega)^2_2$ so it can be $\kappa = \omega$. But weakly compact means uncountable.

Comment: $\kappa$ being weakly compact and $\kappa\to(\kappa)^2_2$ are equivalent for $\kappa>\omega$ of course. Even though it's not written explicitly it's safe to assume that $k$-SRP cardinals (or any other large cardinal) are assumed to uncountable